# Rectangular Fractal name and Area

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, fractals

I would like to know the name of this fractal, and how to obtain the n-th step area. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If it hasn't any name yet, I propose to name it the "Eeeee" fractal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider that the initial area is $1$.

The area diminishing ratio between a step and its successive step is $$r=\dfrac{13}{16}<1.$$

Therefore the area remaining at the $n$-th step is $r^{n-1}$ **which tends to zero when $n$ tends to infinity**, just like the Sierpinski triangle fractal.